# What is a default Spring Boot Application Context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring Framework we can choose the type of application context from the image below:

[image: Spring application context types]

But which one is implemented by default by spring boot?

Does it depend on which starter dependencies we choose when create project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the starter projects you use. For regular projects Spring Boot uses the [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) and for web projects
the [AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/context/AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.html).

See also the output of

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DummyApplication implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DummyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Technically it does not directly depends on the starter , but depends on the value of [`WebApplicationType`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/WebApplicationType.html) you configure to run the application :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(FooApplication.class);
  app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.SERVLET);
  app.run(args);
}
```

If you do not configure it , the default value will be deduced by checking if certain classes exist in the [classpath](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ec2ce10d65042a9b5f436a102e68c60b3bc104a6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/WebApplicationType.java#L74).

There are 3 types of `WebApplicationType` will are `REACTIVE` , `SERVLET` and `NONE`.

And based on its value , it will choose which type of application context to be created for. See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ec2ce10d65042a9b5f436a102e68c60b3bc104a6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L572) for the logic.

- For `REACTIVE` , it will create `AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext`
- For `SERVLET` , it will create `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext`
- For `NONE`, it will create `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`

So it is possible that even you use certain starter , but changing the WebApplicationType value will cause different context type to be used.

Answer (score 4):

We can see the output using the following code as well

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

I used the spring-boot-starter-web dependency , so it printed `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext`

On including `spring-boot-starter` it prints `org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`

So depending one the spring-boot starter dependency , spring is choosing the implementation of `ApplicationContext`